# Getting a day date for last week from a given date

Tags: linux, date

I know how to get the last Saturday date using `date --date="sat. last week" +"%m%d%Y"` However, I am unable to get the last Saturday date for a particular given date.

I am trying to find the date of last saturday date from a given date. For an instance, let us say that the given date is **`20140605`** (in **YYYYMMDD** format) or any weekday date from that particular week. This given date could be any weekday date (20140602-20140606) in the following week for that Saturday, I need to derive the Saturday date for the week before this date which would be (in my case)= **`20140531`**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just barfed a bit on my keyboard, but this seems to work:

```
D="20140605"; date --date "$D $[($(date --date "$D" +%u) + 1) % 7] days ago" +"%Y%m%d"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a small Python snippet for you:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys


fmt = "%Y%m%d"
daystring = sys.argv[1]
day = datetime.strptime(daystring, fmt)


for d in range(7):
    # Go back a few days, but not more than 6.
    testdate = day - timedelta(days=d)
    # If the test date is a saturday (0 is monday, 6 sunday), output that date.
    if testdate.weekday() == 5:
        print testdate.strftime(fmt)
```

Test:

```
$ python test.py 20140605
20140531
```

Comment: I am getting the following error when using your snippet. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_date.py", line 7, in ?
    day = datetime.strptime(daystring, fmt)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'strptime'"

also, can I put the date in a variable? and pass that variable as argument for this snippet?
How can I know what these functions are doing? I tried `man` but it doesn't show anything related to `datetime` or `timedelta`. Appreciate your help if you could let me know what do they mean

Comment: This is a valid program for Python 2(.7). Copy the entire contents to a file, e.g. `test.py`, and execute it the way I have shown. It uses the first argument on the command line as input date. The code is Python, and the modules/function are part of Python's standard library. It's all documented in the Python documentation, not in man pages.

Comment: This snippet should also work for Python 2.5 (which is quite old). That means the error you have observed likely is the result of you not having properly applied the script. As I said, just copy it as is.

Comment: My python version is 2.4.3. I copied all the code exactly from above, and it still gives me the same error. Could this be due to older version?

Comment: Indeed, `datetime.strptime()` has been added in 2.5. Python 2.4 has been released 10 years ago, 2.4.3 is from 2006. Is there a reason to stick to such an old Python? :)

Comment: No reason, it's just that we do not use much of the python coding, so I guess, they did not upgrade. Thank you for the solution though, someone who has the same question and looking for a python snippet might benefit by your answer. Thank you.